# MDX Filter performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx

I have the query below that is dynamically being generated but it takes 10 seconds is there a better way to do this ? There can be 1 to N Farm ID's. I would really like the ID's to be returned in the result set. But if I do it with a where clause with out getting the error

> Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Deliveries], [Measures].[Cows per Delivery] } ON COLUMNS,   NON EMPTY { ([Farm].[Farm Number].[Farm Number].ALLMEMBERS * [Farm].[Farm Name].[Farm Name].ALLMEMBERS, FILTER(  [Farm].[Farm ID].Members,   ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21393) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21395) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21396) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21399) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21400) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21401) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21402) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21403) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21404) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21405) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21406) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21407) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21408) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21410) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21411) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21585) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21590) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21591) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21592) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21593) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21594) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21595) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21596) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21597) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21598) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21599) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21600) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21601) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21602) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21603) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21604) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21605) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21606) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21607) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21608) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21609) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21610) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21611) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21612) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21613) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21614) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21615) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21616) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21617) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21618) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21619) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21620) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21621) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21674) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21676) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21677) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21678) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21679) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21680) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21681) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21682) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21683) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21684) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21686) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21687) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21688) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21689) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21690) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21691) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21692) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21693) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21694) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21974) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21975) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21976) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21977) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21978) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20872) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20873) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20874) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20875) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20876) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20877) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20878) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20879) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20880) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20881) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20882) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20883) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20884) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20885) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20886) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20887) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20888) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20889) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20890) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20891) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20892) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20893) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20894) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20895) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20896) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20897) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20899) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20900) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20901) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20902) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20903) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20904) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20927) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20928) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 20929) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21203) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21757) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21493) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21494) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21496) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21497) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21498) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21499) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21500) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21501) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21502) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21503) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21504) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21505) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21506) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21507) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21508) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21509) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21510) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21511) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21512) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21571) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21587) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21588) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21589) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 22045) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 22046) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 22047) or  ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 22048)  ) ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM(  SELECT ( { [Barn].[Barn ID].&[8141] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM 
( SELECT ( { [Time].[Date].&[2017-02-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2017-02-28T00:00:00] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM
 [Farms])
)
 WHERE ( [Time].[Date].&[2017-02-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2017-02-28T00:00:00] ,
 [Barn].[Barn ID].&[8141]
) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Filter function is really slow, I recommend to avoid it. I'd rewrite:

```
...
[Farm].[Farm Number].[Farm Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Farm].[Farm Name].[Farm Name].ALLMEMBERS *
FILTER(
    [Farm].[Farm ID].Members,   
        ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21393) or ([Farm].[Farm ID].Member_value = 21395) or ...
```

Into:

```
...
[Farm].[Farm Number].[Farm Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Farm].[Farm Name].[Farm Name].ALLMEMBERS *
{[Farm].[Farm ID].&[21393], [Farm].[Farm ID].&[21395] ...}
```

But I'm not sure if Member_value = ID.

The cropped code:

```
Select 
Non Empty { [Measures].[Deliveries], [Measures].[Cows per Delivery] } ON COLUMNS,
Non Empty { 
        [Farm].[Farm Number].[Farm Number].ALLMEMBERS *
        [Farm].[Farm Name].[Farm Name].ALLMEMBERS *
        {
            [Farm].[Farm ID].&[21393],
            [Farm].[Farm ID].&[21395], 
            [Farm].[Farm ID].&[21396],
            [Farm].[Farm ID].&[21399] 
         }
}  ON ROWS 

From [Farms]
Where (
    [Barn].[Barn ID].&[8141],
    {[Time].[Date].&[2017-02-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2017-02-28T00:00:00]}
)
```

You can regenerate your list of [Farm].[Farm ID] and add into the code.

Comment: is there a way I can get the results to include the ID of the farm in the results ? without getting an error like Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function

Comment: I've updated the answer. Does cropped version works for you?

Comment: Yeah I will try it today ... but yes the cropped version will be fine thanks for the help!

Comment: I get a error Query (3, 11) Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function

Comment: I'm sorry for my untidiness. I wasn't able to test the code. I've fixed it.

Comment: can you explain what you fixed ? I am trying to learn MDX as I go

Comment: replace , with *.